# strange error logged in error.log

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

When I refresh my website I get following error logged in tmp/logs/error.log:

```
2012-10-30 18:38:50 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class JsController could not be found.
#0 /var/www/mysite/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

This is strange because webservice works perfectly, everythings is ok and I dont get any error on website.

My question is how I can track this error to find a cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a JS-file returns a 404, either from your project or a plugin you are using (DebugKit or something). Turn on firebug (Net-Tab) and make sure that all files look as they should ..

hope that helps

Comment: perfect - that was it, thanks! Its strange why Cake didn't write to error log something like - "couldnt load somescript.js"...